# How to create Apache Arrow vectors for writing to a Table in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, apache-arrow

I am trying to write a method that takes a column of data, `data: any[]` and packs it into an Arrow-typed Array Buffer to put into an Arrow table.

For example, if I have Type.Float64, I can do this:

```
Float64Vector.from(toFloat64Array(data));
```

But for `Int64Vector`, `TimeSecondVector`, or `TimestampVector`, I'm getting errors:

```
TimestampVector.from(data)
error: Type 'AbstractVector<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'BaseVector<any>': offset, VectorName, values, typeIds, and 7 more.ts(2740)
```

```
DecimalVector.from(data), TimeSecondVector.from(data), and BinaryVector.from(data)
Type 'AbstractVector<any>' is not assignable to type 'BaseVector<any>'.ts(2322)
```

I have been combing the documentation and I cannot find anything that explains how to use this.  I just want to know how I can build these types of Vectors:

```
TimeSecondVector
TimestampVector
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Apache Arrow provides `Builders`! [Great doc about builders](http://arrow.apache.org/docs/js/classes/builder.html)

Also, do not trust this:

```
Float64Vector.from(toFloat64Array(data));
```

for any of the data types.  Builders seem to be the way to go, until have to start dealing with Uint32Arrays (Decimal and Binary?  That's in another question).

```
export const createTimeSecondVector = (data: number[]): TimeSecondVector => {
  const builder = TimeSecondBuilder.new({
    type: new TimeSecond(),
    nullValues: [null, undefined]
  });
  data.forEach(d => {
    builder.append(d);
  });
  return builder.finish().toVector();
};
```

```
export const createTimestampVector = (data: number[]): TimestampVector => {
  const builder = TimestampBuilder.new({
    type: new Timestamp(TimeUnit.SECOND, 'America/Denver'),
    nullValues: [null, undefined]
  });
  data.forEach(d => {
    builder.append(d);
  });
  return builder.finish().toVector();
};
```